# How to use add a string into a sql statement?

Tags: python, sql

Is there any way I can use a string variable and insert it into an sql statement. e.g

```
x = 'column_0 = 1'

cur.execute('SELECT DISTINCT * FROM fifaplayers WHERE ? ', (x,))
```

Something like this?

Comment: You can't put column names into query parameters. You can insert the column name name into the query string itself, if you have to.

Comment: If you had `WHERE col = ?`, your code might already be working (depending on your particular underlying database).  Yes, the RHS can be a parameter, no, the LHS cannot be.

Comment: `cur.execute('SELECT DISTINCT * FROM fifaplayers WHERE {0}'.format(x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just concat your strings like this :

```
cur.execute('SELECT DISTINCT * FROM fifaplayers WHERE ' + x)
```

Answer (score 0):

If youre just adding a string...This works:

```
x = 'column_0 = 1'

cur.execute('SELECT DISTINCT * FROM fifaplayers WHERE ' + x)
```

You can concatenate strings in Python